# How do I build an SSRS expression for the NoRowsMessage that shows report parameter values?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, expression

How do I build an SSRS expression for the `NoRowsMessage` that shows report parameter values?

something like:

```
="No locations were found for this street name : " + @StreetName
```

I have also tried this:

```
="No locations were found for this street name : " + Parameters!StreetName.Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second attempt worked fine:

```
="No locations were found for this street name : " + Parameters!StreetName.Value
```

I can add in carriage returns also as per [this article](https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/11/12/creating-a-line-break-within-an-ssrs-expression.html) which suggests the use of vbcrlf

```
=vbcrlf + "No locations were found for this street name : " +  Parameters!StreetName.Value
```